android studio navigation bar
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                myWeb.loadUrl("https://test.net/"); 
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_search:
                myWeb.loadUrl("https://test.net/"); 
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                myWeb.loadUrl("https://test.net/"); 
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});

i have webview app..
I am sure that all identifiers (
R.id.nav_home:, R.id.nav_search:R.id.nav_profile:

error: constant expression required
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                             ^

) are identical to the XML files, but I see this error and the red line below each id.R
Please help me, I am a beginner
Language JAVA
I want to give functionality to the button bar at the bottom of the application interface in the activity file, so that when the user clicks on one of the buttons, he is taken to the desired page.

Note that Java and Javascript are two very different things. I've removed the Javascript tag as it's not relevant

Which Java version do you use in your project?

compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
